# How to determine the focal length of a lens that is equivalent to two lenses?

Tags: optics, lenses

For context on this question, I've included a whole diagram explaining the situation:

[image]

I have a light bulb with a 10° spread that I want to narrow down into a beam and send through a diffraction grating.

The calculation I've done so far requires 3 lenses: the first lens makes the light parallel, the second lens focuses the light, and the third lens makes the light parallel again in a narrow beam.

However, it's certainly possible to consolidate the first two lenses into one lens.

[image]

At the end of the day, I'm going to need to shop for these lenses and the exact sizes I want will not be available so I'll need to figure out how to do this anyways.

**So my question is:** given the beam spread of 10 degrees (represented by f_bulb), and a convex lens (f_lens), where will the beam converge on the other side of the lens (f_focus)?

Comment: I think I may have just found the answer here: https://www.citycollegiate.com/geometricaloptics3.htm

Answer (score 1):

In the [thin lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_length) approximation the following relationship is satisfied 
$$
\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{object} + \frac{1}{image}
$$
where $f$ is the focal length, $object$ is the distance of the lens to the object (your lamp), and $image$ is the distance from the lens to the image. So, if you place the object at the distance $object=2f$, you expect to obtain a focus at $image = 2f$. Nevertheless, since your light source is not a point source, you will encounter several issues.

If I would have to setup the experiment, I would not bother too much about the divergence of the light rays. Instead I would try using an iris to cut out the center part of the light and try to observe something using only this part. If the light intensity is too low, I would buy the cheapest lens with a focal lens of about $f=100mm$ and diameter 1''.

Comment: Hmm. My goal here is to capture as much light as possible. Considering LEDs aren't going to give a good spectrum, I'm relying on a halogen bulb the the power/heat/luminance trade-off isn't ideal.